# PyQt5: call method from first window in second window

Tags: python, methods, pyqt5, qmainwindow

I have two windows in this PyQt5 GUI application.

I need to call a function in the first window from second window on button press event. ( I am using python 3.8.10 )

I just want to load data from excel when I press an insert button in the second window. But `loadExcelData()` is in the first window class.

I have tried this method :

```
class second(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow2):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.insertDatabtn.clicked.connect(self.getAndInsert)
    
    def getAndInsert(self):
        f1 = first()      
        f1.loadExcelData()
```

Full code :

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import relativedelta
import ast,time

class Ui_MainWindow1(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(710,500)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(264, 248))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.insertWindowbtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.insertWindowbtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(546, 30, 135, 51))
        # EDIT
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Calibri")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.headlabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.headlabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 30, 221, 51))
        self.headlabel.setFont(font)
        #self.headlabel.setText('Expiration Detector')
        self.headlabel.setObjectName("headlabel")
        # END
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Lucida Sans")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setItalic(False)
        # EDIT 2
        self.profilebtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.profilebtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(546, 85, 135, 51))
        self.profilebtn.setFont(font)
        self.profilebtn.setText('')
        self.profilebtn.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(QtGui.QPixmap(r"user.png")))
        self.profilebtn.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(28, 28))
        self.profilebtn.setText("   Profile   ")
        self.profilebtn.setObjectName("profilebtn")
        # END 2
        self.insertWindowbtn.setFont(font)
        self.insertWindowbtn.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(QtGui.QPixmap('plus.png')))
        self.insertWindowbtn.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(28, 28))
        self.insertWindowbtn.setObjectName("insertWindowbtn")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 150, 660, 321))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.insertWindowbtn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " Add Data"))
    
    def show_new_window(self, checked):
        self.w = second()
        self.w.show()

class Ui_MainWindow2(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(484,338)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(264, 248))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        #MainWindow.setLayout(layout)
        
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle("Insert Data Window")

        self.insertDatabtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.insertDatabtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 250, 121, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Lucida Sans")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.insertDatabtn.setFont(font)
        self.insertDatabtn.setObjectName("insertDatabtn")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 101, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Lucida Sans")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 101, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Lucida Sans")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 140, 101, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Lucida Sans")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 200, 101, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Lucida Sans")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.txtDescription = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.txtDescription.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 22, 271, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Lucida Sans")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.txtDescription.setFont(font)
        self.txtDescription.setObjectName("txtDescription")
        self.txtSerialno = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.txtSerialno.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 82, 271, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Lucida Sans")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.txtSerialno.setFont(font)
        self.txtSerialno.setObjectName("txtSerialno")
        self.dateExpire = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(self)
        self.dateExpire.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 200, 131, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Lucida Console")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.dateExpire.setFont(font)
        self.dateExpire.setDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime(QtCore.QDate(2020, 12, 30), QtCore.QTime(0, 0, 0)))
        self.dateExpire.setCurrentSection(QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit.DaySection)
        self.dateExpire.setCalendarPopup(True)
        self.dateExpire.setObjectName("dateExpire")
        self.dateIssue = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(self)
        self.dateIssue.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 140, 131, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Lucida Console")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.dateIssue.setFont(font)
        self.dateIssue.setDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime(QtCore.QDate(2020, 12, 30), QtCore.QTime(0, 0, 0)))
        self.dateIssue.setCurrentSection(QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit.DaySection)
        self.dateIssue.setCalendarPopup(True)
        self.dateIssue.setObjectName("dateIssue")
        # Set 
        self.insertDatabtn.setText("Insert Data")
        self.label.setText("Description")
        self.label_2.setText("Serial No")
        self.label_3.setText("Issue Date")
        self.label_4.setText("Expire Date")
        self.dateExpire.setDisplayFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
        self.dateIssue.setDisplayFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")

class first(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow1):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Expiration Monitor")
        
        # Load data from excel file
        df = pd.read_excel("CadetData.xlsx", "Sheet1") 
        if df.size == 0:
            return

        dfc = str(df.columns) #Extracting list of header labels
        HeaderLabels = ast.literal_eval(dfc[dfc.find('['):dfc.find(']')+1])
        for i in HeaderLabels :
            for i in HeaderLabels :
                if 'Unnamed' in i :
                    HeaderLabels.remove(str(i))    
        HeaderLabels.append('Remaining Time')
        HeaderLabels.append('Remaining %')

        df.fillna('', inplace=True)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(df.shape[0])
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(df.shape[1]+2)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(HeaderLabels)
        ExpireDates = []
        IssueDates = []
        # returns pandas array object
        for row in df.iterrows():
            values = row[1]
            
            ExpireDates.append(values['Expire Date'])
            IssueDates.append(values['Issue Date'])

            for col_index, value in enumerate(values):
                #if isinstance(value, (float, int)):
                #    value = '{0:0,.0f}'.format(value)
                tableItem = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(value))
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row[0], col_index, tableItem)

        for i in range(len(ExpireDates)) :

            end_date = datetime.strptime(ExpireDates[i], "%d/%m/%Y")
            start_date = datetime.strptime(datetime.today().strftime('%d/%m/%Y'),"%d/%m/%Y")
            # Get the relativedelta between two dates
            delta = relativedelta.relativedelta(end_date, start_date)
            # Time to expire
            if delta.years < 0 or delta.months < 0 or delta.days <0 :
                remtime = '0 Years 0 Months 0 Days'
            else :
                remtime = str(delta.years)+' Years,'+str(delta.months)+' Months,'+str(delta.days)+' Days'

            end_date2 = datetime.strptime(ExpireDates[i], "%d/%m/%Y")
            start_date2 = datetime.strptime(IssueDates[i], "%d/%m/%Y")
            # Get the relativedelta between two dates
            delta2 = relativedelta.relativedelta(end_date2, start_date2)
            #total days from issue date to expire date
            totday = (delta2.years*365)+(delta2.months*30)+delta2.days

            tabItem = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(remtime)
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i, 4, tabItem)
            # Remaining days to expire
            remday = (delta.years*365)+(delta.months*30)+delta.days
            # Remaining months to expire
            #remmonth = (delta.years*12)+delta.months

            if remday >= (12*30) :
                Pcolor = "#1ac73a" # Green color
            elif remday > (6*30) :
                Pcolor = "#db8514" # Orange color
            elif remday >= (3*30) or remday < (3*30) :
                Pcolor = "#d61515" # Red color


            Pbar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self)
            Pstyle = """
QProgressBar {
     border: 2px solid #5c5c5c;
     border-radius: 5px;
     text-align: center;
 }

 QProgressBar::chunk {
     background-color: """+Pcolor+""";
     width: 20px;
 }
"""
            Pbar.setStyleSheet(Pstyle)
            Pbar.setFormat("%p%")
            self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(i,5,Pbar)
            prec = int((remday/totday)*100)
            if prec<0:
                prec=0
            Pbar.setValue(prec)

        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(0, 110)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(1, 100)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(2, 70)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(3, 70)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(4, 150)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(5, 140)

        for x in range(df.shape[0]):
            self.tableWidget.setRowHeight(x,28)

        self.tableWidget.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QTableWidget.NoEditTriggers)

        # Button Connects
        self.insertWindowbtn.clicked.connect(self.OpenInsertWindow)

    def OpenInsertWindow(self):
        self.show_new_window(self)
    """
    def InsertData(self):
        from openpyxl import load_workbook
        
        myFileName=r'CadetData.xls'
        #load the workbook, and put the sheet into a variable
        wb = load_workbook(filename=myFileName)
        ws = wb['Sheet1']
        #max_row is a sheet function that gets the last row in a sheet.
        newRowLocation = ws.max_row +1
        #write data
        
        ws.cell(column=1,row=newRowLocation, value="aha! a new entry at the end")
        wb.save(filename=myFileName)
        wb.close()"""

    def loadExcelData(self): 

        print('Fn Call 200')
        # Load data from excel file
        df = pd.read_excel("CadetData.xlsx", "Sheet1") 

        if df.size == 0:
            return

        dfc = str(df.columns) #Extracting list of header labels
        HeaderLabels = ast.literal_eval(dfc[dfc.find('['):dfc.find(']')+1])
        for i in HeaderLabels :
            for i in HeaderLabels :
                if 'Unnamed' in i :
                    HeaderLabels.remove(str(i))    
        HeaderLabels.append('Remaining Time')
        HeaderLabels.append('Remaining %')

        df.fillna('', inplace=True)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(df.shape[0])
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(df.shape[1]+2)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(HeaderLabels)
        ExpireDates = []
        IssueDates = []
        # returns pandas array object
        for row in df.iterrows():
            values = row[1]
            
            ExpireDates.append(values['Expire Date'])
            IssueDates.append(values['Issue Date'])

            for col_index, value in enumerate(values):
                #if isinstance(value, (float, int)):
                #    value = '{0:0,.0f}'.format(value)
                tableItem = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(value))
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row[0], col_index, tableItem)

        for i in range(len(ExpireDates)) :

            end_date = datetime.strptime(ExpireDates[i], "%d/%m/%Y")
            start_date = datetime.strptime(datetime.today().strftime('%d/%m/%Y'),"%d/%m/%Y")
            # Get the relativedelta between two dates
            delta = relativedelta.relativedelta(end_date, start_date)
            # Time to expire
            if delta.years < 0 or delta.months < 0 or delta.days <0 :
                remtime = '0 Years 0 Months 0 Days'
            else :
                remtime = str(delta.years)+' Years,'+str(delta.months)+' Months,'+str(delta.days)+' Days'

            end_date2 = datetime.strptime(ExpireDates[i], "%d/%m/%Y")
            start_date2 = datetime.strptime(IssueDates[i], "%d/%m/%Y")
            # Get the relativedelta between two dates
            delta2 = relativedelta.relativedelta(end_date2, start_date2)
            #total days from issue date to expire date
            totday = (delta2.years*365)+(delta2.months*30)+delta2.days

            tabItem = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(remtime)
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i, 4, tabItem)
            # Remaining days to expire
            remday = (delta.years*365)+(delta.months*30)+delta.days
            # Remaining months to expire
            #remmonth = (delta.years*12)+delta.months

            if remday >= (12*30) :
                Pcolor = "#1ac73a" # Green color
            elif remday > (6*30) :
                Pcolor = "#db8514" # Orange color
            elif remday >= (3*30) or remday < (3*30) :
                Pcolor = "#d61515" # Red color


            Pbar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self)
            Pstyle = """
QProgressBar {
     border: 2px solid #5c5c5c;
     border-radius: 5px;
     text-align: center;
 }

 QProgressBar::chunk {
     background-color: """+Pcolor+""";
     width: 20px;
 }
"""
            Pbar.setStyleSheet(Pstyle)
            Pbar.setFormat("%p%")
            self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(i,5,Pbar)
            prec = int((remday/totday)*100)
            if prec<0:
                prec=0
            Pbar.setValue(prec)

        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(0, 110)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(1, 100)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(2, 70)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(3, 70)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(4, 150)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(5, 140)

        for x in range(df.shape[0]):
            self.tableWidget.setRowHeight(x,28)

        self.tableWidget.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QTableWidget.NoEditTriggers)

        # Button Connects
        self.insertWindowbtn.clicked.connect(self.OpenInsertWindow)

class second(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow2):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.insertDatabtn.clicked.connect(self.getAndInsert)
    
    def getAndInsert(self):
        dataCol1 = self.txtDescription.text()
        dataCol2 = self.txtSerialno.text()
        dataCol3 = self.dateIssue.text()
        dataCol4 = self.dateExpire.text()
        
        from openpyxl import load_workbook
        
        myFileName=r'CadetData.xlsx'
        #load the workbook, and put the sheet into a variable
        wb = load_workbook(filename=myFileName)
        ws = wb['Sheet1']
        #max_row is a sheet function that gets the last row in a sheet.
        #newRowLocation = ws.max_row +1
        for max_row, row in enumerate(ws, 1):
            if all(c.value is None for c in row):
                newRowLocation = max_row
                break

        #write data
        try:
            ws.cell(column=1,row=newRowLocation, value=dataCol1)
            ws.cell(column=2,row=newRowLocation, value=dataCol2)
            ws.cell(column=3,row=newRowLocation, value=dataCol3)
            ws.cell(column=4,row=newRowLocation, value=dataCol4)

            wb.save(filename=myFileName)
            wb.close()
        except Exception as e:
            msg1 = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
            #msg1.setIcon(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning)
            msg1.setText(str(e))
            msg1.setWindowTitle("Error")
            msg1.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Ok)
            msg1.exec_()
        else:
            f1 = first()       #  <<
            f1.loadExcelData() #  << Is this correct ?
            msg2 = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
            #msg2.setIcon(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information)
            msg2.setText("Successfully Inserted Data.")
            msg2.setWindowTitle("Success")
            msg2.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Ok)
            msg2.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = first() 
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Is there any other method? Because this method does not work.
I have searched many times and couldn't find a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the first window from the second window, you can pass a reference to the first window in the `__init__` for the second window and set it as an attribute. Then you can use `self.first_window` wherever you need to access the first window within the second window (and *vice versa*).

I have made all the necessary changes to your example in the code below (search for `#->` to find them all):

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import relativedelta
import ast,time

class Ui_MainWindow1(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(710,500)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(264, 248))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.insertWindowbtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.insertWindowbtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(546, 30, 135, 51))
        # EDIT
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Calibri")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.headlabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.headlabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 30, 221, 51))
        self.headlabel.setFont(font)
        #self.headlabel.setText('Expiration Detector')
        self.headlabel.setObjectName("headlabel")
        # END
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Lucida Sans")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setItalic(False)
        # EDIT 2
        self.profilebtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.profilebtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(546, 85, 135, 51))
        self.profilebtn.setFont(font)
        self.profilebtn.setText('')
        self.profilebtn.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(QtGui.QPixmap(r"user.png")))
        self.profilebtn.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(28, 28))
        self.profilebtn.setText("   Profile   ")
        self.profilebtn.setObjectName("profilebtn")
        # END 2
        self.insertWindowbtn.setFont(font)
        self.insertWindowbtn.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(QtGui.QPixmap('plus.png')))
        self.insertWindowbtn.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(28, 28))
        self.insertWindowbtn.setObjectName("insertWindowbtn")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 150, 660, 321))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.insertWindowbtn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " Add Data"))

    #-> REMOVE THIS METHOD
    # def show_new_window(self, checked):
    #    self.w = second()
    #    self.w.show()


class Ui_MainWindow2(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(484,338)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(264, 248))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        #MainWindow.setLayout(layout)

        MainWindow.setWindowTitle("Insert Data Window")

        self.insertDatabtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.insertDatabtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 250, 121, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Lucida Sans")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.insertDatabtn.setFont(font)
        self.insertDatabtn.setObjectName("insertDatabtn")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 101, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Lucida Sans")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 101, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Lucida Sans")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 140, 101, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Lucida Sans")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 200, 101, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Lucida Sans")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.txtDescription = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.txtDescription.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 22, 271, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Lucida Sans")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.txtDescription.setFont(font)
        self.txtDescription.setObjectName("txtDescription")
        self.txtSerialno = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.txtSerialno.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 82, 271, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Lucida Sans")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.txtSerialno.setFont(font)
        self.txtSerialno.setObjectName("txtSerialno")
        self.dateExpire = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(self)
        self.dateExpire.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 200, 131, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Lucida Console")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.dateExpire.setFont(font)
        self.dateExpire.setDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime(QtCore.QDate(2020, 12, 30), QtCore.QTime(0, 0, 0)))
        self.dateExpire.setCurrentSection(QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit.DaySection)
        self.dateExpire.setCalendarPopup(True)
        self.dateExpire.setObjectName("dateExpire")
        self.dateIssue = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(self)
        self.dateIssue.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 140, 131, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Lucida Console")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.dateIssue.setFont(font)
        self.dateIssue.setDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime(QtCore.QDate(2020, 12, 30), QtCore.QTime(0, 0, 0)))
        self.dateIssue.setCurrentSection(QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit.DaySection)
        self.dateIssue.setCalendarPopup(True)
        self.dateIssue.setObjectName("dateIssue")
        # Set
        self.insertDatabtn.setText("Insert Data")
        self.label.setText("Description")
        self.label_2.setText("Serial No")
        self.label_3.setText("Issue Date")
        self.label_4.setText("Expire Date")
        self.dateExpire.setDisplayFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
        self.dateIssue.setDisplayFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")

class first(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow1):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Expiration Monitor")

        # Load data from excel file
        df = pd.read_excel("CadetData.xlsx", "Sheet1")
        if df.size == 0:
            return

        dfc = str(df.columns) #Extracting list of header labels
        HeaderLabels = ast.literal_eval(dfc[dfc.find('['):dfc.find(']')+1])
        for i in HeaderLabels :
            for i in HeaderLabels :
                if 'Unnamed' in i :
                    HeaderLabels.remove(str(i))
        HeaderLabels.append('Remaining Time')
        HeaderLabels.append('Remaining %')

        df.fillna('', inplace=True)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(df.shape[0])
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(df.shape[1]+2)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(HeaderLabels)
        ExpireDates = []
        IssueDates = []
        # returns pandas array object
        for row in df.iterrows():
            values = row[1]

            ExpireDates.append(values['Expire Date'])
            IssueDates.append(values['Issue Date'])

            for col_index, value in enumerate(values):
                #if isinstance(value, (float, int)):
                #    value = '{0:0,.0f}'.format(value)
                tableItem = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(value))
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row[0], col_index, tableItem)

        for i in range(len(ExpireDates)) :

            end_date = datetime.strptime(ExpireDates[i], "%d/%m/%Y")
            start_date = datetime.strptime(datetime.today().strftime('%d/%m/%Y'),"%d/%m/%Y")
            # Get the relativedelta between two dates
            delta = relativedelta.relativedelta(end_date, start_date)
            # Time to expire
            if delta.years < 0 or delta.months < 0 or delta.days <0 :
                remtime = '0 Years 0 Months 0 Days'
            else :
                remtime = str(delta.years)+' Years,'+str(delta.months)+' Months,'+str(delta.days)+' Days'

            end_date2 = datetime.strptime(ExpireDates[i], "%d/%m/%Y")
            start_date2 = datetime.strptime(IssueDates[i], "%d/%m/%Y")
            # Get the relativedelta between two dates
            delta2 = relativedelta.relativedelta(end_date2, start_date2)
            #total days from issue date to expire date
            totday = (delta2.years*365)+(delta2.months*30)+delta2.days

            tabItem = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(remtime)
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i, 4, tabItem)
            # Remaining days to expire
            remday = (delta.years*365)+(delta.months*30)+delta.days
            # Remaining months to expire
            #remmonth = (delta.years*12)+delta.months

            if remday >= (12*30) :
                Pcolor = "#1ac73a" # Green color
            elif remday > (6*30) :
                Pcolor = "#db8514" # Orange color
            elif remday >= (3*30) or remday < (3*30) :
                Pcolor = "#d61515" # Red color


            Pbar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self)
            Pstyle = """
QProgressBar {
     border: 2px solid #5c5c5c;
     border-radius: 5px;
     text-align: center;
 }

 QProgressBar::chunk {
     background-color: """+Pcolor+""";
     width: 20px;
 }
"""
            Pbar.setStyleSheet(Pstyle)
            Pbar.setFormat("%p%")
            self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(i,5,Pbar)
            prec = int((remday/totday)*100)
            if prec<0:
                prec=0
            Pbar.setValue(prec)

        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(0, 110)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(1, 100)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(2, 70)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(3, 70)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(4, 150)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(5, 140)

        for x in range(df.shape[0]):
            self.tableWidget.setRowHeight(x,28)

        self.tableWidget.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QTableWidget.NoEditTriggers)

        # Button Connects
        self.insertWindowbtn.clicked.connect(self.OpenInsertWindow)

    def OpenInsertWindow(self):
        #-> PASS REFERENCE TO FIRST WINDOW
        self.second_window = second(self)
        self.second_window.show()

    """
    def InsertData(self):
        from openpyxl import load_workbook

        myFileName=r'CadetData.xls'
        #load the workbook, and put the sheet into a variable
        wb = load_workbook(filename=myFileName)
        ws = wb['Sheet1']
        #max_row is a sheet function that gets the last row in a sheet.
        newRowLocation = ws.max_row +1
        #write data

        ws.cell(column=1,row=newRowLocation, value="aha! a new entry at the end")
        wb.save(filename=myFileName)
        wb.close()"""

    def loadExcelData(self):

        print('Fn Call 200')
        # Load data from excel file
        df = pd.read_excel("CadetData.xlsx", "Sheet1")

        if df.size == 0:
            return

        dfc = str(df.columns) #Extracting list of header labels
        HeaderLabels = ast.literal_eval(dfc[dfc.find('['):dfc.find(']')+1])
        for i in HeaderLabels :
            for i in HeaderLabels :
                if 'Unnamed' in i :
                    HeaderLabels.remove(str(i))
        HeaderLabels.append('Remaining Time')
        HeaderLabels.append('Remaining %')

        df.fillna('', inplace=True)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(df.shape[0])
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(df.shape[1]+2)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(HeaderLabels)
        ExpireDates = []
        IssueDates = []
        # returns pandas array object
        for row in df.iterrows():
            values = row[1]

            ExpireDates.append(values['Expire Date'])
            IssueDates.append(values['Issue Date'])

            for col_index, value in enumerate(values):
                #if isinstance(value, (float, int)):
                #    value = '{0:0,.0f}'.format(value)
                tableItem = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(value))
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row[0], col_index, tableItem)

        for i in range(len(ExpireDates)) :

            end_date = datetime.strptime(ExpireDates[i], "%d/%m/%Y")
            start_date = datetime.strptime(datetime.today().strftime('%d/%m/%Y'),"%d/%m/%Y")
            # Get the relativedelta between two dates
            delta = relativedelta.relativedelta(end_date, start_date)
            # Time to expire
            if delta.years < 0 or delta.months < 0 or delta.days <0 :
                remtime = '0 Years 0 Months 0 Days'
            else :
                remtime = str(delta.years)+' Years,'+str(delta.months)+' Months,'+str(delta.days)+' Days'

            end_date2 = datetime.strptime(ExpireDates[i], "%d/%m/%Y")
            start_date2 = datetime.strptime(IssueDates[i], "%d/%m/%Y")
            # Get the relativedelta between two dates
            delta2 = relativedelta.relativedelta(end_date2, start_date2)
            #total days from issue date to expire date
            totday = (delta2.years*365)+(delta2.months*30)+delta2.days

            tabItem = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(remtime)
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i, 4, tabItem)
            # Remaining days to expire
            remday = (delta.years*365)+(delta.months*30)+delta.days
            # Remaining months to expire
            #remmonth = (delta.years*12)+delta.months

            if remday >= (12*30) :
                Pcolor = "#1ac73a" # Green color
            elif remday > (6*30) :
                Pcolor = "#db8514" # Orange color
            elif remday >= (3*30) or remday < (3*30) :
                Pcolor = "#d61515" # Red color


            Pbar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self)
            Pstyle = """
QProgressBar {
     border: 2px solid #5c5c5c;
     border-radius: 5px;
     text-align: center;
 }

 QProgressBar::chunk {
     background-color: """+Pcolor+""";
     width: 20px;
 }
"""
            Pbar.setStyleSheet(Pstyle)
            Pbar.setFormat("%p%")
            self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(i,5,Pbar)
            prec = int((remday/totday)*100)
            if prec<0:
                prec=0
            Pbar.setValue(prec)

        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(0, 110)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(1, 100)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(2, 70)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(3, 70)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(4, 150)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(5, 140)

        for x in range(df.shape[0]):
            self.tableWidget.setRowHeight(x,28)

        self.tableWidget.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QTableWidget.NoEditTriggers)

        # Button Connects
        self.insertWindowbtn.clicked.connect(self.OpenInsertWindow)

class second(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow2):
    #-> CHANGE SIGNATURE
    def __init__(self, first):
        super().__init__()
        #-> ADD REFERENCE TO FIRST WINOW
        self.first_window = first
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.insertDatabtn.clicked.connect(self.getAndInsert)

    def getAndInsert(self):
        dataCol1 = self.txtDescription.text()
        dataCol2 = self.txtSerialno.text()
        dataCol3 = self.dateIssue.text()
        dataCol4 = self.dateExpire.text()

        from openpyxl import load_workbook

        myFileName=r'CadetData.xlsx'
        #load the workbook, and put the sheet into a variable
        wb = load_workbook(filename=myFileName)
        ws = wb['Sheet1']
        #max_row is a sheet function that gets the last row in a sheet.
        #newRowLocation = ws.max_row +1
        for max_row, row in enumerate(ws, 1):
            if all(c.value is None for c in row):
                newRowLocation = max_row
                break

        #write data
        try:
            ws.cell(column=1,row=newRowLocation, value=dataCol1)
            ws.cell(column=2,row=newRowLocation, value=dataCol2)
            ws.cell(column=3,row=newRowLocation, value=dataCol3)
            ws.cell(column=4,row=newRowLocation, value=dataCol4)

            wb.save(filename=myFileName)
            wb.close()
        except Exception as e:
            msg1 = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
            #msg1.setIcon(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning)
            msg1.setText(str(e))
            msg1.setWindowTitle("Error")
            msg1.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Ok)
            msg1.exec_()
        else:
            #-> ACCESS FIRST WINOW
            self.first_window.loadExcelData()
            msg2 = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
            #msg2.setIcon(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information)
            msg2.setText("Successfully Inserted Data.")
            msg2.setWindowTitle("Success")
            msg2.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Ok)
            msg2.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = first()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```